# How do I disable dynamic page titles or the blue notification dot in Firefox for specific domains?

Tags: firefox, dynamic, notifications, title

Firefox perpetually displays a blue dot notification for pages where the title constantly changes. This is particularly annoying for pages like TradingView or GDAX, where the title changes constantly with price updates. On the other-hand, this is extremely useful for pages like Gmail. So I don't want to disable it across the board - just for specific domains.

[image]

I would normally just go back to Chrome, but Firefox 57 is so much faster on my MacBook.

How do I disable dynamic page titles or the blue notification dot in Firefox for specific domains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it like this for Stack Overflow's website:

1. Open `about:config` in Firefox
2. Search for the `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` and set it to `true`
3. Open your Firefox profile folder (under *Settings* → *Help* → *More troubleshooting information* → *Profile folder* → *Open folder*)
4. Create a new folder `chrome` and within this folder a new file `userChrome.css`
5. Open the new file and paste the following content into it:

```css
@-moz-document url(chrome://browser/content/browser.xhtml) {

  .tabbrowser-tab[label*="Stack Overflow"] > .tab-stack > .tab-content[pinned][titlechanged]:not([selected="true"]) {
      background-image: none !important;
      }
    }
```

6. Restart Firefox

The CSS selector `[label*="Stack Overflow"]` needs to match the title of a browser tab partially. If you omit it, the blue dot will be disabled globally for all tabs.

Credits go to these sources:
https://www.userchrome.org/how-create-userchrome-css.html
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1270061
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1181537

Comment: Do you know what the correct syntax would be if you had multiple tabs that you wanted to apply this solution to?

Comment: No, unfortunately not :( but a short search for "CSS logical OR" brought me some promising results. A not so nice but easy solution would be to simply duplicate the code

Answer (score 0):

Write an extension or userscript that prevents the title from being modified, e.g. by replacing the setters on the title element and its text content node with noops.

Note that you will have to access the untrusted page context to do so, since extensions run in a a separate context.